# Reporting Moran's I test results in a paper

Tags: r, spatial, glm

I have tested spatial auto-correlation in a generalised linear model using Moran's I test (`DHARMa` package).
I got results for observed, expected, sd and p-value and the result is there's no auto-correlation.
How do one report the result of Moran's I in a scientific paper? Is the p-value itself enough or should I report any of the other results?

Thanks

Comment: Would this question be better posted on Cross Validated (StackExchange statistics)?

Comment: Thanks Peter,
I'm quite new to this so did not think of this option. Will try though.

Comment: You question seems to be one about statistics rather than coding, hence the comment. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a matter of preference, but I err on the side of more information. For example:

*"The residuals of the GLM did not exhibit spatial autocorrelation (Moran's I = −0.061; p = 0.54)."*

Or perhaps follow standard practice in your field.